# Reading value from other thread.

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I created a thread. 
How can I read values of variables from GUI thread?

I know how to change them. I don't know how to read them.

This is what I'm using for changing things on GUI thread:

```
    public void Log(string message)
    {
        MethodInvoker m = () => { Log_textBox.Text += message; };
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            BeginInvoke(m);
        }
        else
        {
            Invoke(m);
        }
    }
```

I need to read some values from GUI thread:

```
    public void StartBot()
    {
        Klient.StartBot(selectedType, (int)nb_count.Value, nb_nonstop.Checked, (...)int.Parse(extra_set.SelectedItem.ToString()));
    }

    private void StartStopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            Thread questThread = new Thread(StartBot);
            Klient.RequestToStop = false;
            questThread.Start();
    }
```

I'm getting cross thread operation error on line with Klient.StartBot(...) argument list.

How to fix it?

Comment: If you are on .NET 4.0 (vs 2010) then there is a lot of new material around ASYNC that should cover what you are looking for http://www.wischik.com/lu/AsyncSilverlight/AsyncSamples.html

Comment: If `InvokeRequired` is false , you don't need to call `Invoke`.  You can just call `m();`.

Comment: @Cos: No; that's C# 5 CTP, and not very relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return a value from an invoked delegate by creating a `Func<ReturnType>`.
`Invoke` will return the function's return value.

Alternatively, you can set a local variable inside the delegate and call it using `Invoke` (not `BeginInvoke`, since that won't wait for it to finish)

Comment: `var result = (int)Invoke(new Func<int>(delegate { return 7; }));`